# Regular expression timezone

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for valid time zone, tried the following one.
But I'm not sure about it.
Please help me to find out anything wrong in the following regular expression.

#### Edited:

Here colon and minutes are optional. how can i change it to mandatory.
If there is no minutes user should input 00 (+05:00).
Please help me to solve this issue.

```
var chkzone = "+05:30"
if(chkzone .match(/^(Z|[+-](?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9])(?::?(?:[0-5]?[0-9]))?)$/))
{
    alert('works out');
}
else
{
    alert("Time zone wrong")
}
```

Comment: This looks like JavaScript. Why is there a Java tag?

Comment: I think more examples of potential input, or at least a better description of what a "valid time zone" is, would be helpful.

Comment: this works for +05 or +05:30 . The colons and minutes are optional.

Comment: have you tried something like http://regexsr.oxgva.com/ to do some tests?

Comment: your regex seems to work, but i don't undestand the interest of plus/minus for 24 hours format (e.g +23:45)

Comment: @ Vinayak Pingale now i noticed your point (The colons and minutes are optional) how to change it to colons and minutes are must values. The user should input colon and minutes. If there is no minutes they should input 00 ie +05:00. Please help me to change the expression

Comment: Should `+0:0` or `+9:8` be valid? Right now, it is, and I don't think that makes sense. Also `Z` (all by itself) is a valid timezone according to this regex. Keep it or toss it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following regex matches timezones with mandatory double digit hours/minutes, or the letter `Z`:

```
/^(?:Z|[+-](?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9])$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
^            # Start of string
(?:          # Match the following non-capturing group:
 Z           # Either a literal Z
|            # or
 [+-]        # a plus or minus sign
 (?:         # followed by this non-capturing group:
  2[0-3]     # Either a number between 20 and 23
 |           # or
  [01][0-9]  # a number between 00 and 19
 )           # End of inner non-capturing group
 :           # Match a literal colon
 [0-5][0-9]  # Match a number between 00 and 59
)            # End of outer non-capturing group
$            # End of string
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/aT2vU2).

Comment: +0:0 or +9:8 is not valid. How to restrict this one too ? ie +05:30 is valid but +5:30 is not valid

Comment: @Dibish: By removing the `?` quantifier which means "zero or one matches of the preceding token". I've updated the regex and added a link to a testing site.

Comment: Regx has to be refined further. Timezone has a range from -12:00 to +14:00 and not gradually increasing by 00:30 always. Anyway this helped me to validate a timepicker with little change :) Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If what you really want is a Regex for a timezone, something that works better is the following:

`^(?:(?:[A-Za-z_\-]+\/[A-Za-z_\-]+(?:\/[A-Za-z_\-]+)?)|(?:Etc\/[A-Za-z0-9+\-]+(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9]+)?|(?:CET|CST6CDT|EET|EST|EST5EDT|MET|MST|MST7MDT|PST8PDT|HST)))$`

Regex tester: https://regexr.com/7ig42

Your question is more about a **Timezone Offset** than a timezone in the IANA format, but I came here and found your question while looking for IANA regex.