# JavaScript check if timezone name valid or not

Tags: javascript, timezone, timezone-offset

Is there a way to check if timezone name valid or not in JavaScript without using external library?

When user enters timezone name in text field I want to verify whether zone is valid or not?

I know we can do it easily using moment-timezone library. But I don't want to use any extra library. I'm looking for pure JavaScript way.

```
isValidTimeZone(name) {
//return true/false  
}

isValidTimeZone('Asia/Colombo'); //returns true
isValidTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'); //returns true
isValidTimeZone('MyTimeZone/ME'); //returns false
```

Comment: Time zones are not considered valid based on the friendly location name (as you show in your question), they are valid based on 
 a time zone offset. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609927/regular-expression-timezone

Comment: User enters timezone name (ex: Asia/Colombo). Later I need to use this in Highcharts. So need to validate this. User will not enter +05:30.

Comment: What makes a time zone valid for you? Is `America/Anaheim` valid? Because I don't think you mean that anything in "Continent/City_Name" format is automatically valid. You must have some database to test against.

Comment: Do you feel like maintaining [this data](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json) yourself? Seems like a lot of trouble to go to in order to avoid using a library.

Comment: If you don't want use an external lib then there's no magic but write a map yourself. Checkout https://github.com/dmfilipenko/timezones.json or moment-timezone for a reference.

Comment: They aren't just "friendly" names, they are identifiers in the tz database.  The list is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In environments that fully support IANA time zone identifiers in ECMA-402 (ECMAScript Internationalization API), you can try using a time zone in a `DateTimeFormat` (or in the options of to `toLocaleString`) and it will throw an exception if it is not a valid time zone.  You can use this to test for validity, but only in environments where it is supported.

```
function isValidTimeZone(tz) {
    if (!Intl || !Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone) {
        throw new Error('Time zones are not available in this environment');
    }

    try {
        Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, {timeZone: tz});
        return true;
    }
    catch (ex) {
        return false;
    }
}

// Usage:
isValidTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles') // true
isValidTimeZone('Foo/Bar') // false
```

If you cannot be assured of your environment, then the best way would be with moment-timezone

```
!!moment.tz.zone('America/Los_Angeles') // true
!!moment.tz.zone('Foo/Bar') // false
```

Of course, you could always extract your own array of time zone names (perhaps with `moment.tz.names()` and test against that.

Answer (score 15):

in typescript you could also do in a more cleaner way

```
    public static isValidTimezone(timezone: string): boolean {
            return moment.tz.zone(timezone) != null;
        }
```

you need to also import

```
import moment = require("moment-timezone");
```

Answer (score 10):

I took [Matt Johnson-Pin solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118363/13784984), after writing unit tests I found if to pass `undefined` the function returns `true`. So I made small update:

```
export const isValidTimeZone = (tz: unknown): boolean => {
    try {
        if (!Intl || !Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone) {
            return false
        }

        if (typeof tz !== 'string') {
            return false
        }

        // throws an error if timezone is not valid
        Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, { timeZone: tz })
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        return false
    }
}
```

Thanks anyway I use this in production.

Comment: Just adding to this answer, "Time zones are not available in this environment" is not entirely true. Some user supporting timeZone have the locale of timeZone set to undefined for some reason (maybe browser preference or something) but still able to use the timeZone on DateTimeFormat, so a slightly different check id need